# Cannot change global keyboard shortcuts in Linux Mint XFCE

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, window-manager

I am using Linux Mint 14 XFCE.  I am trying to remove the default XFCE window manager shortcuts for workspace switching (Ctrl-F1, Ctrl-F2, etc.), as described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/xfce-4-change-global-keyboard-shortcuts).

The answers there don't have any effect for me.  If I go into Settings->Window Manger->Keyboard, nothing I do has any effect.  If I click on a setting and hit "Clear", the setting stays there unchanged.  If I double-click on a setting and choose a new shortcut key, the original settings stays there unchanged.  If I go into Settings Editor (as described in the other answer to that question) and attempt to reset the settings there, nothing has any effect still.

What is going on?  How can I get XFCE to let me change the keyboard shortcut settings?

Comment: This [link](https://wiki.xfce.org/faq) could be a good start point for a solution.Take a look at "Keyboard" section

Comment: @MickyInTheSky: That page says "The shortcuts to handle the window manager are defined in the Settings Manager > Window Manager Settings > Keyboard."  That's what I'm already using, but it has no effect.  It also says something about a "default theme" and creating a new theme, but my settings manager doesn't have any such thing (there is only the list of shortcuts, no way to create a new theme).

Comment: It is a strange behavior. I'm using linux Mint 13 and I 'm able to manage the shortcuts with the command line:    xfce4-keyboard-settings

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in mint 17 xfce (with both wm shortcuts like Ctrl-F1 and keyboard shortcuts like Alt-F2). I don't like the way how I fixed it but I could not find a better solution. First, I searched for all keyboard configuration files:

```
$ locate xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
/usr/share/mint-configuration-xfce/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

Then I removed the file from `home`, did copies of system files and removed all shortcuts which I wanted to free in both system files. After reboot these shortcuts finally gone.

Comment: Instead of removing the `~/.config` file, I suggest just deleting its contents, but leave it behind. (It got recreated on next login when I deleted the whole file.)