# Xfce 4: how to change keyboard shortcuts globally (for all user accounts)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, window-manager, accounts

I changed some window manager shortcuts through **Window Manager**>>**Keyboard** and **Keyboard**>>**Shortcuts**. Now, as it happens these changes take effect only on the account where they were set (I'm using Xfce 4.10).

So the question is how to propagate them to all other user accounts? OR how to set them globally and not on per user account manner in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thx to answer to this question: [Cannot change global keyboard shortcuts in Linux Mint XFCE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/cannot-change-global-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux-mint-xfce) I found quite an easy way to propagate all made changes to other user accounts on a system.

Just copy your local configuration file named **xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml** (located here: *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/*) over the same file in other accounts. Job done.