# how to bind commands like "Ctrl+C" to one-key (for example "F5")?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

I use some commands very frequently. Some of them are several keys combinations. And my fingers are not quite satisfied with them. So it looks usable for me to bind them to one-key commands.

For example, I want to map Ctrl+C function to F5 key (not killing Ctrl+C but adding one). What way is preferable for doing such binding in X11? I cant't find any.

Comment: What WM/DE are you using?

Comment: @A.P. Xfce 4.12

Answer (score 1):

If you're under XFCE:

1. install `xdotool`
2. open the [Xfce Settings Manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/xfce-4-change-global-keyboard-shortcuts)
3. make the F5 key run `xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c`.

This will send <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> to the currently focused/active window.